# How to Modify App Icon and App Name for MDM Distribution – Rebranding of Native App

Tags: android, ios, iphone, icons, mdm

We leverage third-party services for our organization which provides employees services. The native Android and iOS apps are part of these services and distrusted in our organization by using MDM (AirWatch) solution. The vendor provides only binaries and NOT Source Code, as they share the same solution with many different organizations.

Currently, the vendor unable to provide customized binaries with our brand icon and app name. We would like to create and distribute a fully branded version of the app for our organization.

Is there any way to **modify App Icon and App Name** (which appear on device) for Binaries of native Android and iOS Apps?

Or is there any custom build tool from which we can re-bundle the binaries with our app icon and name? It would be okay even its a repeatable process with each release.

Comment: i mean, you could technically decompile the app and change anything you'd want to, but that's _technically_ true. if there's obfuscation or anything like that involved, you probably won't succeed. a bit broad to be asking here how to do it though i think

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android but for iOS you would need the provisioning profile, certificate and key. (I imagine you don't have these)

You can then modify the app payload and then re-sign the ipa. I have done this a number of times to update an expiring profile on some of our enterprise apps.

Here is a useful tool for re-signing .ipa files https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign